# ActiveRecord::StaleObject error on opening each result on a new tab

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Recently we've added a functionality in our RoR application which allows users to open a particular record, let's say in their own individual tabs. Doing so, we've started seeing frequent `ActiveRecord::StaleObject` errors. On investigating the issue I found that rails is indeed trying to update the session store first whenever a resource is opened in a tab and the exception is raised.

We've `lock_version` in our active record session store, so Rails is taking it as optimistic locking by default. Is there any way we could solve this issue without introducing much complexity, as the application is already live on the client's machine and without affecting any sessions' data we've stored in our session store DB.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to a session object stored in the database that's raising the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using optimistic locking on a db session record and updating the session record when you process an update to other records. Not sure what you'd need to update in the session, but if you're worried about possibly conflicting updates to the session object (and need the locking) then these errors might be desired.

If you don't - you can refresh the session object before saving the session (or disable it's optimistic locking) to avoid this error for these session updates.

You also might look into what about the session is being updated and whether it's strictly necessary. If you're updating something like "last_active_on" then you might be better off sending off a background job to do this and/or using the `update_column` method which bypasses the rather heavyweight activerecord save callback chain.

--- UPDATE ---

**Pattern: Putting side-effects in background jobs**

There are several common Rails patterns that start to break down as your app usage grows. One of the most common that I've run into is when a controller endpoint for a specific record also updates a common/shared record (for example, if creating a 'message' also updates the `messages_count` for a user using [counter cache](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/19/activerecords-counter-cache.html), or updates a `last_active_at` on a session). These patterns create bottlenecks in your application as multiple different types of requests across your application will compete for write locks on the same database rows unnecessarily.

These tend to creep into your app over time and become hard to refactor later. I'd recommend *always* handling side-effects of a request in an asynchronous job (using something like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)). Something like:

```rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :enqueue_update_messages_count_job
  def enqueue_update_messages_count_job
    Jobs::UpdateUserMessageCountJob.enqueue(self.id)
  end
end
```

While this may seem like overkill at first, it creates an architecture that is significantly more scalable. If counting the messages becomes slow... that will make the job slower but not impact the usability of the product. In addition, if certain activities create lots of objects with the same side-effects (lets say you have a "signup" controller that creates a bunch of objects for a user that all trigger an update of `user.updated_at`) it becomes easy to throw out duplicate jobs and prevent updating the same field 20 times.

**Pattern: Skipping the activerecord callback chain**

Calling `save` on an ActiveRecord object runs validations and all the `before` and `after` callbacks. These can be slow and (at times) unnecessary. For example, updating a `message_count` cached value doesn't necessarily care about whether the user's email address is valid (or any other validations) and you may not care about other callbacks running. Similar if you're just updating a user's `updated_at` value to clear a cache. You can bypass the activerecord callback chain by calling `user.update_attribute(:message_count, ..)` to write that field directly to the database. In theory this shouldn't be necessary for a well designed application but in practice some larger/legacy codebases may make significant use of the activerecord callback chain to handle business logic that you may not want to invoke.

--- Update #2 ---

**On Deadlocks**

One reason to avoid updating (or generally locking) a common/shared object from a concurrent request is that it can introduce Deadlock errors.

Generally speaking a "Deadlock" in a database is when there are two processes that both need a lock the other one has. Neither thread can continue so it must error instead. In practice, detecting this is hard, so some databases (like postgres) just throw a "Deadlock" error after a thread waits for an exclusive/write lock for x amount of time. While contention for locks is common (e.g. two updates that are both updating a 'session' object), a true deadlock is often rare (where thread A has a lock on the session that thread B needs, but thread B has a lock on a different object that thread A needs), so you may be able to partially address the problem by looking at / extending your deadlock timeout. While this may reduce the errors, it doesn't fix the issue that the threads may be waiting for up to the deadlock timeout. An alternative approach is to have a short deadlock timeout and rescue/retry a few times.

Comment: I just disabled optimistic locking as I realized that we actually don't need it in the first place. I put the `ActiveRecord::Base.lock_optimistically = false` in application.rb file and I can say the frequency of ActiveRecord::StaleObject exception has reduced.
Edit: I am kind of curious about the second part where you mentioned a background job to handle `update_column` part. Can you please share shed some more light on that or where I can read more about that part? Thanks :)

Comment: sure - i'll update the answer, let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @melcher. Although, on going through the options, I feel this might be an overkill but necessary to resolve our application exceptions. Disabling optimistic lock did resolve `ActiveRecord::StaleObject` exception, but now on rare cases I am facing `ActiveRecord::Deadlocked` exception. I'm positive this is due to `active_record_store` trying to update the session data on each request. I guess following the pattern to skip activerecord callback chain might help resolve this issue?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. This is exactly the kind of thing that you avoid by doing updates to shared records using an asynchronous job. Updated the answer again to add a note about deadlocks.